# TypeError: undefined is not a function in node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get data from server and show it on web page but
 I am getting a error at  end of file

response.end(body);

TypeError: undefined is not a function

i don't get what the error is please help

My Nodejs Code

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();

var request = require('request');
var passport = require('passport')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser     =        require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/service',function(req,res){
    var id = req.query.name; 
    console.log('hi');
    console.log(id);
    request.post({
                 headers: {
                            //set header if needed
                           },
                 url    : 'http://example.com:8080/rest/api/2/issue/id',
                 json   : {
                             userName:'username',
                             password:'password'
                           }
                },
                function(error, response, body){
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        response.end(body);
                    }
            });
});
console.log('running');
app.listen(8082);
```

Comment: What is the linenumber of the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `res` variable, which is the response object passed into your Express request handler:

```
res.end(body);
```

`response` is an object passed by the `request` library that you're using, which is a different thing.